WPF + CommunityToolkit.Mvvm how to implement undo/redo commands
i'm wondering what is the best way to implement custom Undo/Redo commands?
In my case, I am implementing a diagram editor and I want to create Undo/Redo commands to undo manipulations on canvas elements, for example to undo rotation, move or resize an element.
Ideas I'm not sure of:
-Write my own implementation of ICommand or a derived class from RelayCommand and store commands in the main View Model in stacks;
-Write a repository that will store command stacks in session memory and a service that will implement Register, Execute and Undo methods.

Is it only Commands to be handled by Undo/Redo or also e.g Property changes?

Hi Klaus, only for commands

The command isn't the thing to focus on. The main issue is representing the different versions. Linked list of diffs or stack of stares are usually options.

If someone interested, this is how i implemented it for my case:
/// <summary>
/// An interface that defines base methods to manage undoable commands.
/// </summary>
public interface IUndoableCommandManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">Target command with execution logic.</param>
    public void Execute(IUndoableCommand command);
    /// <summary>
    /// Cancels the effects of an command execution.
    /// </summary>
    public void Undo();
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs command execution again.
    /// </summary>
    public void Redo();
    /// <summary>
    /// Clears history of all commands inside manager.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear();
}

/// <summary>
/// A class that implements <see cref="IUndoableCommandManager"/>. Manages undoable commands.
/// </summary>
public sealed class UndoableCommandManager : IUndoableCommandManager
{
    private readonly Stack<IUndoableCommand> _undoStack = [];
    private readonly Stack<IUndoableCommand> _redoStack = [];

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether an undo operation can be performed.
    /// </summary>
    private bool CanUndo => _undoStack.Count > 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether a redo operation can be performed.
    /// </summary>
    private bool CanRedo => _redoStack.Count > 0;

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Execute(IUndoableCommand command)
    {
        command.Execute(null);
        _undoStack.Push(command);
        _redoStack.Clear();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Undo()
    {
        if (CanUndo)
        {
            var command = _undoStack.Pop();
            command.Undo();
            _redoStack.Push(command);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Redo()
    {
        if (CanRedo)
        {
            var command = _redoStack.Pop();
            command.Execute(null);
            _undoStack.Push(command);
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Clear()
    {
        _undoStack.Clear();
        _redoStack.Clear();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// An interface expanding <see cref="ICommand"/> with undo behavior.
/// </summary>
public interface IUndoableCommand : ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Undoes previous execution.
    /// </summary>
    void Undo();
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UndoableCommand"/> class that can undo previous execution.
/// </summary>
public sealed class UndoableCommand : IUndoableCommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Action _undo;

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UndoableCommand"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="undo">The undo behavior logic.</param>
    public UndoableCommand(Action execute, Action undo)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(execute);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(undo);

        _execute = execute;
        _undo = undo;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter = null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Execute(object? parameter = null)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void Undo()
    {
        _undo();
    }
}

